# Save finger image into mySQl from fingerprint reader device in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, fingerprint

I want to store Finger Print Image into mySql Database and move it into folder through fingerprint reader device (device name: digital persona) in PHP. can Any one help please by sharing code .

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: This is not a "give me the code" website. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -2):

You **can not** store the image directly in the database. 
But what you want can be achieved by following these steps:

1. Upload the image (probably at your host or any third party file manager)
2. Get the location of the stored image.
3. Upload the location of the image in the database.

and when you want to display it, just get the location of the image from database and use it as you want!

Thanks.

Comment: ever heard of the The BINARY and VARBINARY types ?

Comment: Thanks , But before uploading image my First step is to read image from device and shows it into web application . As like biometric devices which reads image from device and showing there pic in specified area. I want same as in PHP or javascript

Comment: Different devices will have different ways to get the image (that is device specific).